# Vimeo Native Play Button Toggle Class?

Tags: jquery, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have the following which is a custom play button for a Vimeo video, it works fine. Click play the video fade out...

The issue is that if you click play on the native default Vimeo controls, my custom play icon remains over the video whilst its playing.

Is there anyway to toggle a class from clicking the native play button on the Vimeo play?

So if you click either play button my custom one is removed?

```
if ($("#showreel")[0]) {
                var iframe = document.getElementById('showreel');
                if ( typeof iframe !== 'undefined' ) {
                  // $f == Froogaloop
                  var player = $f(iframe);
                  // bind events
                  var playButton = document.getElementById("play-button");
                  playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                  $( playButton ).toggleClass('video_playing');        
                  player.api("play");
            });
        }
  }
```

Comment: I guess you would have to subscribe to the play/pause events to detect that kind of status change - and then check whether it was triggered by your own button, or otherwise (which would then mean the default control, presumably.)

Comment: I wouldn’t know even where to start with your suggestion, only just managed to get a button to play the video!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried capturing the play EVENT ?
https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#play

```
player.on('play', function(data) {
    // toggle your class
});
```

Comment: since you are using jquery .. why don't you use the jquery api https://github.com/jrue/Vimeo-jQuery-API your code in the fiddle fails to detect the player .. that is why it does not work